# Is there a Linux tool for defragging NTFS partitions?

Tags: ntfs, fsck

Can NTFS partitions be defragged within Linux? Does fsck work for this?
(Here and there I've seen a recommendation to use `fsck -t ntfs --kerneldefrag /dev/XXX`. Would this work?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a universal tool that can do defragmentation on linux called [shake](http://vleu.net/shake). You can [download the source](https://github.com/unbrice/shake), or for Ubuntu users there's a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~un-brice/+archive/ppa) (the `shake` package in the official repository is unrelated).

I've just tested it on an NTFS filesystem mounted using [ntfs-3g](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download) and it seemed to work without problems (no errors, the verbose output looks typical). So probably is filesystem-independent... Almost, since it *can* make use of extended attributes. To work without making use of those, you should use the `-X` option. Try using

```
shake --old=0 -v -X /some/directory/
```

From my experience, it has to be run as root.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such tool for linux.
you have to boot windows for that.

Comment: Where does the recommendation about using `fsck` come from, I wonder.

Comment: @BeSlayed an idiot or a jokester?

Comment: The answer is at least imprecise. True, there is probably no such tool that does this **at low level**, but defragmentation can be performed at higher level to a mounted filesystem (probably any).

Comment: Mighty google says Ultra Defrag is being ported: http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html